# How to have redux dispatch be local to the instance instead of global?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Suppose on the same page,

I have two instances of the same component. Both of them call the same dispatch except with different parameters and thus effect each other.

Is there any way to fix this other than get rid of redux?

Thank you

Comment: is `dispatch` supposed to effect both? If so, then how can't you fix this by removing redux? Basically i'm saying redux isn't the issue, you might have some logic dependency.

Comment: OFC they call the same `dispatch`, they are dispatching to the same Redux store. Are you saying you want these two components to operate independent of one another? If so then each will need its own state and set of actions.

Comment: nah dispatch is supposed to affect only one... even though they are the same redux. Yeah, think I have to remove redux. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very purpose of Redux is single shared piece of state(with high control over changes through action/reducer, middleware to improve flexibility, performance-related wrappers etc - but that is just additions)

If you really want component to have independent data, you should not use Redux, but integrate local state with [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) or [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)(or `this.state` if for any reason you use class components). By the way, `useReducer` utilizes the same concept of reducer/action but since it does not have concept of middleware I'd suggest consider `useState` first, before trying to integrate somehow existing Redux actions with `useReducer`

That does not look really probable to me, but in case you want to reuse the same logic to those components as well as to Redux actions (say, same endpoint, the same logic to process response) you can extract some logic into separate function so both Redux action creator and those components would take benefit of reusing it